# Can I store data in an ERC20 token?

Tags: string, tokens

Can i store data, e.g. a string inside a token? If so, this data will follow the token around if I transfer it to someones wallet?

Comment: You can do this by appending data along with the transfer function

Comment: Could you elaborate?

When you say "along with", you mean inside, just as part of the function execution?

Comment: question was poorly considered. I'm actually interested in creating an integer token that cannot be divided. Then storing associating a string with the token in the blockchain.